# Will Google OAuth continue to work with JavaFX WebView

Tags: google-oauth

The following article outlines changes to google oauth for webviews, https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html?m=1

"In the coming months, we will no longer allow OAuth requests to Google in embedded browsers known as 'web-views'".

Will there by any changes to google oauth support in the JavaFX WebView? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: It hasn't stopped working yet.